# karma tests in angular not functioning in components

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

When I run some karma tests, and create a 1st.spec.ts like in the [tutorial](https://angular.io/guide/testing), it works without any problem. But when I try to create a xxxx.component.spec.ts, none of the tests run, not even the 1st.spec.ts will run.

edit:
I debugged systematically to pinpoint the problem:

```
beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ LoginComponent ], // declare the test component
    });


  });
```

Comment: Which tutorial? and can you be more precise on your question?

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/testing

Comment: If you check the index.html from this https://angular.io/generated/live-examples/testing/1st-specs.eplnkr.html. They have hardcoded the spec file within configuration. That is why you are not able to rename the file and test.

Comment: my problem here is declaring a test component, see above code

Comment: The code you are showing against the problem you are seeking seems to be inappropriate here. How will that configuration be responsible for running the test? Still not clear whats's the exact issue here.

Comment: You claim that when you add more specs, they do not run. How is that related to your code here?

Comment: If I remove the above code, the previous specs will then run

Comment: In which file do you have that above code? And which file are you referring to previous specs?

Answer (score 0):

Not the best way though, but still this should solve your problem.

This solution is w.r.t the tutorial you are following https://angular.io/generated/live-examples/testing/1st-specs.eplnkr.html

Add all your test specs to the `__spec_files__` array in `index.html`

```
var __spec_files__ = [
      'app/1st.spec', 'app/xxx.spec', 'app/yyy.spec'
    ];
```

I have created a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/T2OLS5IUvoS9LPJdxBdO?p=preview) for the above explanation